# pass id out of model hash. Rails4 strong params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I am struggling with passing :project_id value into :comments model while having nested resources. Hash that is passing from form looks like this:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", 
"comment"=>{"title"=>"sdfs", "desc"=>"ddf"}, 
"commit"=>"Create Comment", 
"project_id"=>"1"}
```

And my permit attributes method as below:

```
params.require(:comment).permit(:title, :desc, :product_id)
```

I was also trying with code as such:

```
  #params.permit(:project_id, comments: [ :title, :desc])
  #params.require(:project_id).permit(:project_id)
  #params.require(:comment).permit(:title, :desc)
```

And my resources:

```
  resources :projects do
    resources :comments
  end
```

Problem is that :title and :desc are inserted but :project_id not... Could you tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

EDIT://
Form that I am using:

```
<%= form_for([@project, @comment]) do |f| %>
  <% if @comment.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@comment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this comment from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @comment.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :desc %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :desc %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Why is project_id not inside comment hash?

Comment: I do not know, how can I pass it inside it? In edit I will paste my current form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `#require` multiple times:

```
params.require(:project_id)
params.require(:comment).permit(:title, :desc)
```

See: https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#require-multiple-parameters

Alternatively, you could pass the `project_id` via a hidden field in the form:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :project_id, value: @project.id %>
```

This would include the `project_id` as a nested attribute in the `comment`. Then you could use:

```
params.require(:comment).permit(:title, :desc, :project_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
params.permit(:project_id, comment: [ :title, :desc])
```

Note that its `comment` and not `comments`

Comment: Sorry but it does not work, I get:
  unknown attribute: comment
      
  <pre># POST /comments.json
  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save</pre>

Answer (score 0):

Wrong, maybe, in this sentence

```
params.require(:comment).permit(:title, :desc, :product_id)
```

Need :project_id

Comment: That is just a typo, with :project_id it doesnt work neither :(